# Pandas to spreadsheet with repeated columns and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a pandas data frame like this

```
data = [['NGS_34',0.47,0.55,0.51,0.53,0.54,0.62], ['NGS_38',0.52,0.52,0.49,0.51,0.52,0.45]]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['probes','01_PLAGL1', '02_PLAGL1','H19','H19', 'H19','GNAS A/B'])
df = df.set_index('probes')
df

             01_PLAGL1  02_PLAGL1   H19   H19   H19  GNAS A/B
probes                                                  
NGS_34       0.47       0.55  0.51  0.53  0.54      0.62
NGS_38       0.52       0.52  0.49  0.51  0.52      0.45
```

This is actually a minimal reproducible example. The real data frame is formed by many paired columns like the example `01_PLAGL1  02_PLAGL1`, then 2 sets of three columns like the example  `H19   H19   H19` and 2 unique columns. With this explanation and the columns of my real dataset below, I think you will understand the input data of my problem.

```
data_no_control.columns.values

array(['PLAGL1', 'PLAGL1', 'GRB10', 'GRB10', 'MEST', 'MEST', 'H19', 'H19',
       'H19', 'KCNQ1OT1', 'KCNQ1OT1', 'MEG3', 'MEG3', 'MEG8', 'MEG8',
       'SNRPN', 'SNRPN', 'PEG3', 'PEG3', 'PEG3', 'NESP55', 'GNAS-AS1',
       'GNASXL', 'GNASXL', 'GNAS A/B'], dtype=object)
```

With this, I need to fill an [excel spreadsheet exactly like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aWQc2UUXu5Tuw6EA0ITnRhu_fOkpL3lNNj_5RNHhmZo/edit?usp=sharing)

In the previous code no show here, column B and header (row A) is already filled as in the excel spreadsheet by using openpyxl. But I can't find a way to start filling the values in the table.

Any idea how I could start this?

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Provide your expected output as a table/code.

Comment: Sorry but, this would be very difficult to provide that. I should need to create the output manually and this would be very time-consuming. I think the best way to show this is like that.

Comment: Is there some part of this that's giving you trouble? For example, since you already have the data in the dataframe, are you struggling with how to insert blank rows, or how to output a dataframe as an excel file?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what should be the best way to do this. For example, shall I create the structure required in the panda's data frame and then send this to the spreadsheet. In that case, how reduce the number of columns by increasing the number of rows?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend creating the structure in the dataframe before sending it to the spreadsheet. Formatting an excel spreadsheet in python isn't the most fun task; formatting a dataframe is easier in my opinion. I'd recommend you look into melt() (https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-melt.php). You can use this to get the data into a more normalized state.

Comment: Are your columns in your original data named `PLAGL1` and `PLAGL1` or `01_PLAGL1` and  `02_PLAGL1`?

Comment: So you want two rows between value sets? Use dataframe_to_rows() for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are identically named as in your output of `data_no_control.columns.values`, you can do:

1. `stack` the dataframe
2. `groupby` and get the `cumcount` for each patient, column combination
3. `pivot` and format to get the required structure

```
stacked = df.stack().rename("value").rename_axis(["patient","column"]).reset_index()
stacked["row"] = stacked.groupby(["patient","column"]).cumcount()

output = stacked.pivot(["patient","row"],"column","value").droplevel(1).rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()

>>> output
  patient  GNAS A/B   H19  PLAGL1
0  NGS_34      0.62  0.51    0.47
1  NGS_34       NaN  0.53    0.55
2  NGS_34       NaN  0.54     NaN
3  NGS_38      0.45  0.49    0.52
4  NGS_38       NaN  0.51    0.52
5  NGS_38       NaN  0.52     NaN

# To replace the duplicate "patient" and `NaN` values with blank
output["patient"] = output["patient"].where(~output.patient.duplicated())
output = output.fillna('')

>>> output
  patient GNAS A/B   H19 PLAGL1
0  NGS_34     0.62  0.51   0.47
1                   0.53   0.55
2                   0.54       
3  NGS_38     0.45  0.49   0.52
4                   0.51   0.52
5                   0.52
```

###### Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['NGS_34',0.47,0.55,0.51,0.53,0.54,0.62], 
                   ['NGS_38',0.52,0.52,0.49,0.51,0.52,0.45]], 
                  columns =['probes','PLAGL1','PLAGL1','H19','H19','H19','GNAS A/B']).set_index("probes")

>>> df
        PLAGL1  PLAGL1   H19   H19   H19  GNAS A/B
probes                                            
NGS_34    0.47    0.55  0.51  0.53  0.54      0.62
NGS_38    0.52    0.52  0.49  0.51  0.52      0.45
```